# Turning off logging in maven

Tags: java, maven, logging

I've read several threads about turning off logging.   I'm using dbunit in my test cases, and there'an enormous amount of logging happening and it's failing the Travis CI builds because the log is too big.

Simply put, how do I turn off logging in maven?

Hi have this for my surfire plugin:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <property> 
              <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
              <value>src/test/resources/logging.properties</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
```

I have put the file in src/test/resources/logging.properties

This is the contents:

```
org.dbunit.level=OFF
```

But, when I run the mvn verify:

```
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_definition_id) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_definition_id) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.IntegerDataType - getSqlValue(column=1, resultSet=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@3ad98a3) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=4, columnName=subject_id) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable - getColumnIndex(columnName=subject_id) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - getColumnIndex(columnName=subject_id) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.BigIntegerDataType - getSqlValue(column=2, resultSet=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@3ad98a3) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=4, columnName=cohort_start_date) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_start_date) - start
18:57:06.121 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_start_date) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DateDataType - getSqlValue(column=3, resultSet=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@3ad98a3) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=4, columnName=cohort_end_date) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_end_date) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - getColumnIndex(columnName=cohort_end_date) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DateDataType - getSqlValue(column=4, resultSet=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@3ad98a3) - start
18:57:06.122 [main] DEBUG org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable - getValue(row=5, columnName=cohort_definition_id) - start
```

I am not using any other special libraries in my pom for logging.
This is a shared codebase so out of 'convention' this does have the spring artifacts instaleld, I do not know if these guys 'inject' logging without my knowledge:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.20.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.20.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Update 2019-12-20:
I set up a breakpoint inside the classes in dbunit that were logging, and it appears to be using logback (the LoggerContext is ch.qos.logback.classic).  So, i think the solution here is to figure out how to specify configuration for logback...

Comment: spring does not use `java.util.logging` by default. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.21.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

Comment: Does just adding the spring dependency (test?) to the maven POM make it a spring application?  This is just a simple JAR library...it doesn't use beans or anything. It's just a bunch of java classes.

Comment: DBUnit uses SLF4J for logging. SLF4J can use multiple backends; which one is used in your setup depends on what you put in the class path. What SLF4J dependencies do you have in your Maven setup?

Comment: I have no SLF4J  declared direclty, howeer looking at the 'test dependencies' in the IDE: i do se SLF4j-api-1.7.28.jar.  So, that is being pulled in from somewhere (probably spring boot).

Comment: Also, it looks like logback-core is a dpeendency, but also log4j-over-slf4j...omg this is so confusing.    I have no idea which logging provider is activating.

Comment: One more comment: when i configured the surfire systemPeroperty as described in the intial post, if I set `.level=WARN`, i get a message in the console when surfire starts that it was an invalid log level. If i cahnge it to `.level=OFF`, i don't get a message anymore, but the DEBUG and INFO logs still spam the crap out of my console, so I really have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to understand which logger was being used, and then provide the proper configuration for it.

In my case, it was logback.

I put a logback-test.xml file in my test/resources folder:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

All debug messages are gone! I need to educate myself on how to specify an explicit logging implementation for my build, but I hope this information is useful for others.

Thanks to all who offered comments and ideas. Much appreciated.